# SAP Cloud SDK JavaScript: No CSRF Token for onPremise destination with Location ID

Tags: javascript, sap-cloud-platform, csrf-token, sap-cloud-sdk

I have an application on SAP Cloud Platform which uses the SAP Cloud SDK JavaScript (Version 1.11.3) to communicate with an OnPremise Destination with corresponding Cloud Connector.
Requests work fine when the property "Location ID" is empty on both the Destination and the Cloud Connector.

However, when specifying a value for the Location ID (both on Destination and Cloud Connector) only GET requets work.

Other requets (e.g. PATCH, POST) fail with the following error message:

```
ERR Destination did not return a CSRF token.
This may cause a failure when sending the OData request.
ERR CSRF header response does not include cookies.
...
ERR Error: Create request failed!
...
ERR Caused by:
ERR Error: post request failed!
...
ERR Caused by:
ERR Error: Request failed with status code 403
```

This did not occur when working with the SAP Cloud SDK for Java.

Am I missing something? Should I set the "x-csrf-token" header manually?

Comment: Hello again (I knew I saw that name somewhere already)! From the top of my head I cannot think of any obvious misconfiguration, so this might actually be a bug. I will try to reproduce the issue tomorrow and then give you an update.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was a bug in the SDK and was fixed in version 1.13.1.

Comment: Somehow the comment I wrote yesterday seems to be gone so I'll repeat it. "Hello again and many thanks for the quick support."

Comment: Version 1.13.1 was released today. Please try again and let us know if your issue was indeed resolved.

Comment: Hi, I tested version 1.13.1 and the issue has been resolved. Many thanks!